# iteration with the list monad

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I'm having trouble understanding how the iterative behavior of the list monad can be derived from its [definition](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads).

```
instance Monad [] where
  m >>= f  = concatMap f m
  return x = [x]
  fail s   = []
```

Discussions I've read seem to pass over the question of how `>>=` creates a control structure, as shown most clearly with `do` notation:

```
allEvenOdds :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
allEvenOdds n = do
  evenValue <- [2,4 .. n]               
  oddValue <- [1,3 .. n]                
  return (evenValue,oddValue)
```

Is this built in to Haskell, the way I assume the IO monad's interface to actual i/o is?

Comment: `do` notation is desugared, so it is converted to `[2,4 .. n] >>= \evenValue -> [1, 3 .. n] >>= \oddValue -> return (evenValue, oddValue)`, and depending on the monad type, it will thus result in different semantics. It is thus not "hardwired" to `IO`.

Comment: To go off on a short tangent, `IO` is basically a semi-magic specialization of `State`. The main source of magic (IIUC) is that, even if `runIO` existed, there is no Haskell term you could supply as the initial state. Roughly speaking, you define an `IO` action named `main`, and the runtime executes something like `runIO main MagicStateOfTheWorld` for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, everything is a simple consequence of the Monad instance you quoted (and, since this example uses `do` notation, how that desugars to uses of the `>>=` operator):

```
allEvenOdds n = do
  evenValue <- [2,4 .. n]               
  oddValue <- [1,3 .. n]                
  return (evenValue,oddValue)

-- desugaring the do notation
allEvenOdds n =
  [2,4 .. n] >>= \evenValue ->
  [1,3 .. n] >>= \oddValue ->
  return (evenValue, oddValue)

-- using the list instance of Monad to replace >>= and return
allEvenOdds n =
  concatMap (\evenValue ->
    concatMap (\oddValue -> [(evenvalue, oddValue)]) [1,3 .. n]
  ) [2,4 .. n]
```

which you can hopefully easily see "iterates over" both lists and results in a list of all pairs of (even, odd) with values taken from both lists.

At a high level, we can say that the list monad results in iteration simply because `concatMap`, like `map`, executes the given function for each element of the list, so it implicitly iterates over the list.

Answer (score 1):

The list instance of the `Monad` typeclass models *nondeterminism*: you can see each `var <- someList` as a `for` loop like in Python.

The `do` notation is desugared to `[2,4 .. n] >>= (\evenValue -> [1, 3 .. n] >>= (\oddValue -> return (evenValue, oddValue)))`, so this is equivalent to something in Python like:

```py
    result = []
    for evenValue in range(2, n, 2):
        for oddValue in range(1, n, 2):
            result.append((evenValue, oddValue))
```

or with list comprehension:

```py
    result = [
        (evenValue, oddValue)
        for evenValue in range(2, n, 2)
        for oddValue in range(1, n, 2)
    ]
```

This works since for `instance Monad []`, the expression `[2,4 .. n] >>= (\evenValue -> [1, 3 .. n] >>= (\oddValue -> return (evenValue, oddValue)))` is thus equivalent to:

```
concatMap (\evenValue -> [1, 3 .. n] >>= (\oddValue -> return (evenValue, oddValue))) [2,4 .. n]
```

and thus:

```
concatMap (\evenValue -> concatMap (\oddValue -> [(evenValue, oddValue)]) [1, 3 .. n]) [2,4 .. n]
```

But `do` notation is not "hardwired" to `IO`: `IO` is just an instance of `Monad` that is implemented in such way that one `IO` action will run before the second one. For lists, it thus is implemented in an equivalent way as spanning Python `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mean to suggest that there's a connection between `do` notation and IO, just that the code that actually reads/writes to i/o isn't implemented in Haskell (I would think it's in C?) and I thought there might be something similar with lists. That the behavior can be explained by nesting `concatMap`s just didn't occur to me.